# R apply for two data frames

Tags: r, apply

I can really imagine, that the answer can be found at stackoverflow but then I don't understand it. So this is my question:

I have a data.frame "tmp" which consists of 17 columns and many rows.
What I want to do is to use approx function with the information from tmp row by row using the apply function:

`tmp[,17] <- apply(tmp[,4:16], 1, approx, y = y, x = tmp[,2])`

where y is fix.

My problem is, that I get now a n x n-Matrix because the apply function calculates each pair of `tmp[,4:16]` and `tmp[,2]`. What I need is just the diagonal, i.e.

`(tmp[1,4:16], tmp[1,2]), (tmp[2,4:16], tmp[2,2]), (tmp[3,4:16], tmp[3,2]),...`

And I want to avoid to make things like `diag(apply(...))` or a loop, because I want to reduce calculation time.

I hope someone can help me and thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is that possible? `approx(tmp[1,4:16], tmp[1,2])` throws `Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`.

Comment: You need the nodes in the approx function: `approx(y,tmp[1,4:16],tmp[1,2] )` where y has the same length of tmp[1,4:16]. In my apply function I twisted the `y` and the `tmp[,4:16]` and wrote a new approx function where I put in the vectors in the correct order so completly `tmp[,17] <- apply(tmp[,4:16], 1, approx2, y = y, x = tmp[,2])` with `approx2 <- function(tmp,y,tmp2){approx(y,tmp,tmp2)[[2]] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Note that both `tmp[, 4:16]` and `tmp[, 2]` are using the same row `i`.

```
set.seed(4542)  # make it reproducible

tmp <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20*17), ncol = 17))
y <- rnorm(length(4:16))

s <- sapply(seq_along(tmp[, 1]), function(i) approx(y, tmp[i, 4:16], tmp[i, 2]))
```

Instead of `seq_along(tmp[, 1])` it is also possible to use `seq_len(nrow(tmp))`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: After testing your code (it works very fine!) I have one question. Why is the System time higher when I use your code then using my code from the question, however I get n x n results and with your solution just n results?

Comment: @Chefkoch Just the system time or the total time?

Comment: It is the total time. My version `System.time(replicate(40, diag(apply(tmp[,4:(ncol(tmp)-1)], 1, approx2, y = y, tmp2 = tmp[,2]` gives `User 13.82, System 1.11, Total 14.96` and your version `System.time(replicate(40, sapply(seq_along(tmp[, 1]), function(i) approx(y, tmp[i, 4:16], tmp[i, 2])))` gives  `User 19.95, System 0.00, Total 19.95`

Comment: Ok the fastest way I found is to use my original code and do it in blocks of 10 to avoid unnecessarily many usles results in the n x n Matrix. But thank you very much anyway for your help!